# My Chromium Browser doesn't start / crashes

Tags: chromium, crash, postfix, error-handling

i bought a Intel Compute Stick with Linux Ubuntu 14 on it.

When i try to open Chromium i get a crash/error notification.

I tried to install Chrome via terminal and nothing i have found on the internet could help me.

Maybe one of you knows how to install a browser or fix the Chromium. I don't care what Browser i'm using, i just want internet access.

Comment: How, exactly, did you try to install Chromium? And Chrome? Did you clean up after unsuccessful attempts?

Comment: I started the Intel Stick, installed Ubuntu then i was on the desktop and started chromium, that's all. Maybe i need to update Ubuntu.

Comment: Chromium is not part of the default install of Ubuntu. Did you install it? Or was it pre-installed on the Stick you purchased?